# Search a result in next page reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input, routes

I am having a search bar in my component. I want on click of search, it should call the search action and navigate the result to the parent component.

```
 <input 
              onKeyPress={(event) => {
             if (event.key === "Enter") {
                  this.onSearch(event.target.value);
                }
              }}
              type="text"
            />
```

Method:

```
 onSearch(searchString) {
     // perform Search
     this.props.history.push("/details");
  }
```

I want it to navigate to a details page with the search String, in URL I am expecting something like:
`http://localhost:8080/details?search="searchString"`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: yes, but it is expected that whenever user bookmark the search result, he should land on the same page with the searching options activated. Can you help me with it

Comment: You could handle this in componentDidMount method of che component rendering the /details page: you can check for the presence of the query parameter and handle it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this

```
onSearch(searchString) {
  // perform Search
  this.props.history.push("/details?search=" + encodeURIComponent(searchString));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For me using `router.push` works and search query is passed with query `parameter` and `pathname` can contain which page you want to go navigate to.

Example:

**Step 1:** Importing `useRouter`:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

**Step 2:** Create a router variable:

```
 const router = useRouter();
```

**Step 3:** Use in Event handler in Search(I am using Semantic UI) and using a state called searchText

```
const [searchText, setsearchText] = useState("");
```

You can use Input, I am using Search Component of Semantic UI here:

```
    <Search
              input={{ icon: "search", iconPosition: "left" }}
              showNoResults={false}
              selectFirstResult={true}
              placeholder="Search..."
              value={searchText}
              onSearchChange={(evt, data) => {
                setsearchText(data.value);
              }}
              onKeyPress={e => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                  router.push({
                    pathname: "/listSearch",
                    query: {
                      searchQuery: searchText
                    }
                  });
                }
              }}
            />
```

**Step 4:**
Now when the use for me press enter, onKeyPress will be called and the URL will be as below(listSearch here is a NextJS page):

```
http://www.localhost.com/listSearch?searchQuery=cds
```

**Step 5:**
In the target page in my case `listSearch` you can put below code to get the search string:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

...

const router = useRouter();
const searchQuery =
    router && router.query && router.query && router.query.searchQuery
      ? router.query.searchQuery
      : "";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am able to route it, but my problem is I have to bookmark the page for further usage, so that whenever i send the page link to someone using text or sms, he should be able to open the same page with same search result. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: If you open up for example link directly: `http://localhost:8080/details?search="searchString"` are you not getting the search result ?
Because for me it is doing the search as details is a page and I have taken the URL parameter from routes as shown in the above answer
 Step 5.

Comment: Actually i am using class components in my project, so understand Functional component is getting bit tricky for me.

Comment: can you help me with what to write in my target page as a class component, so if i open the link as : http://localhost:8080/details?search="searchString" , i fall back at the same search result

Comment: Follow the step number 5 of my answer, i hope it helped you.